# CNN on word vectors throws input dimension error

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, word2vec, conv-neural-network

I have a dataframe with approximately 14560 word vectors of dimension 400. I have reshaped each vector in 20*20 and used 1 channel for applying a CNN so the dimension has become `(14560,20,20,1)`. When I try to fit the CNN model it throws an error.

Code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import backend as K

model_cnn=Sequential()
model_cnn.add(Convolution2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = (3, 3), 
activation='relu',input_shape = (20, 20,1)))

model_cnn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adadelta', 
metrics=["accuracy"])

model_cnn.fit(x_tr_,y_tr_,validation_data=(x_te_,y_te))
```

Error:

> Error when checking target: expected conv2d_6 to have 4 dimensions,
>   but got array with shape (14560, 1). When I reshape train data to
>   (14560,1,20,20) still it gives error as model receives input
>   =(1,20,20) and required is (20,20,1).

How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The problem is not only with `x_tr` shape, which should be `(-1,20,20,1)` as correctly pointed out in another answer. It's also the network architecture itself. If you do `model_cnn.summary()`, you'll see the following:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 18, 18, 16)        160       
=================================================================
Total params: 160
Trainable params: 160
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The output of the model is rank 4: `(batch_size, 18, 18, 16)`. It can't compute the loss when the labels are `(batch_size, 1)`.

### Solution

The correct architecture must reshape the convolutional output tensor `(batch_size, 18, 18, 16)` to `(batch_size, 1)`. There can be many ways to do it, here's one:

```py
model_cnn = Sequential()
model_cnn.add(Convolution2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(20, 20, 1)))
model_cnn.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=18))
model_cnn.add(Flatten())
model_cnn.add(Dense(units=1))
model_cnn.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=["accuracy"])
```

The summary:

```py
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 18, 18, 16)        160       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 1, 1, 16)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 17        
=================================================================
Total params: 177
Trainable params: 177
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Note that I added max-pooling to reduce `18x18` feature maps to `1x1`, then flatten layer to squeeze the tensor to `(None, 16)` and finally the dense layer to output a single value. Also pay attention to the loss function: it's `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. If you wish to do `categorical_crossentropy`, you have to do one-hot encoding and output not a single number, but the probability distribution over classes: `(None, classes)`.

By the way, also check that your validation arrays have valid shape.